# how to use an installed pip3 package on command line

Tags: python, pip

i made a pip3 package `example-pkg-martinbarker-test` online [here](https://pypi.org/project/example-pkg-martinbarker-test/0.0.1/) that just prints a command. I installed it with `pip install example-pkg-martinbarker-test==0.0.1` , how do I run the installed pip3 package from my terminal command line?

I'm trying to find a command like `python3 -m example-pkg-martinbarker-test` that will run my package from the command line, but all the resources online when I look for this information are just about installing packages. please help, I know this must be incredibly simple

Comment: Did you add code into `__init__.py`? Because that's what runs

Comment: Please do a Google search before asking.

Comment: @MadPhysicist I googled it multiple times but found no answer. yes I have code in ym init file: https://github.com/MartinBarker/pypi-package/blob/master/example_pkg/__init__.py

Comment: I typed your title into google and got about 3-4 answers from SO that were relevant. I don't mean just googling as such. I also imply reading very carefully and understanding the search results.

Comment: @MadPhysicist searches for 'how to run a python3 pip3 package from command line' only brings up results for how to install packages. these first 4 results dont mention how to run a pip package from the command line: https://docs.python.org/3/installing/index.html, https://packaging.python.org/tutorials/installing-packages/, https://help.dreamhost.com/hc/en-us/articles/115000699011-Using-pip3-to-install-Python3-modules, https://datatofish.com/install-package-python-using-pip/

Comment: the answer given for this post is not correct

Answer (score 0):

if i well understand, you need first import your package in your python code (a python file) then call its functions

Comment: is there any way to make a python package that people can use from the command line?

Comment: you can run python script in cmd line ,  you can make scripts(python files) then run them in cmd or terminal, for exmple you have a file scr.py that contains  "print(sys.argv[1])" . to run this scrpit using  cmd "python scr.py sssssssss"  the output will  be  sssssssss

Comment: @Martin. You need to create a script in the package, or use an entry point, or create an executable module and run it.